# Publish single exe file for win form application

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce, dotnet-cli, single-file

I tried this command:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true --output "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test_zone\TestCompile"
```

But it outputs:

> Nothing to do. None of projects specified contain packages to restore

- This application has been running/built normally
- This is Visual Studio 2019 Community
- This is .NET, not .NET Core
- I have added ClickOnce publish installed
- I added into the `project.csproj`:

  ```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
      <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
      <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
      <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
      <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```

I am out of ideas. I have read much about publishing single files but it all seems that there is something very simple that I missed.

Comment: *This is .net, not .net core* -- but `dotnet` is a .net core command.

Comment: @LeiYang I have no idea. It should have said the command not available or something. Is there a way to publish single file in .net?

Comment: [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge), [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody)

Comment: @LeiYang I couldn't understand how to use them. Is there resources of steps taken to use them?

Comment: `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>` was already there or you added it?  .NET 5 is the continuation of .NET Core, not .NET Framework.  I think you need to take a step back and show/describe the project you started with rather than your failed steps at publishing it because, if this truly is a .NET Framework project, those Core-specific steps would be misguided, too.